# Should I become a senior programmer before I can become a software architect/lead-tech/CTO of a tech company?

Tags: hiring-process, software-development, project-management, leadership, teamleader

I am a graduated CS, mid-level developer with few self project experiences in Angular/Android-Java/SQlite/JavaScript Node.JS/MongoDB/C#/Python/C++ embedded-linux systems- OpenCV, etc.

I have a vast but not very deep knowledge/experience in different fields of computer science/engineering, and what I want to do is to create some development teams and leading them to create market level products, not just MVP/educational level products that I could do with myself.

I have some ideas about web/mobile apps. I have some ideas about IoT/embedded system products. I have some ideas about machine learning/vision- voice recognition and NLP products, etc.

I think it's hard(maybe impossible, as I tried it for few years) to become a senior developer in web/mobile app in front/back end parts, also in linux-microcontroller embedded programming, beside machine learning and deep neural networks. **But I very love to convert my ideas to real products. I like to have developer teams that I can telling them about my ideas and what products I need, then they will creat it perfectly**

**Why I can't create such teams is because I think, how can I lead developers/engineers they are better than me in that field? They have more knowledge and experiences, so how can I guide them? How is it possible a person with little knowledge/experience can lead a person with more of them? How can I make right decisions between framework A and B, using language C or B, and either implementing our app architecture based on OOP, MVC, etc? Should we using SQL or no-SQL DB? How can I evaluate their work and say you are working as expected or you just cheating(Or just had bad decisions) in underneath layers to complete the project sooner but I must pay a lot to rewrite the project in future, or maybe it's not maintainable/extendable for future developers!**

Because of these fears and not answered questions I tried to become master of the technologies I want for implementing my ideas but they will change day to day and there exist a lot of them to learn and it's even hard to become a master in only one of them.

So I am very disappointed and stopped here and really don't know what to do. **What I'm only sure about myself is having good ideas about new products and mediocre knowledge/experience to create a MVP of that idea in few months, but what I need is creating ready to market products that I can sell to customers and ensure about it's quality/performance/safety as well.**

Thank you for reading my long story and I am really appreciate you to write your comment/experience and ideas about it.

Comment: Is short story of this question "How can a person with lesser experience/knowledge lead and guide/lead people with more experience/knowledge"?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, Yes, almost. With an extra question: "How to architect/structure/design your projects correctly if you have mediocre knowledge/experience in technologies you want to use."

Comment: What's wrong with the most obvious answer: don't do it youself and hire someone who knows this stuff?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul: How to trust? Or how to find a right one and working with him/her?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul: I also like to know how can I become one of them?

Comment: Now that's a whole other question altogether. Most people have a network of people to leverage to have someone trusted by the time they decide to start a business. If you do not, well, you probably shouldn't start a business and focus on that first. And then there is that old saying that if you cannot find someone to start a business with you, you probably shouldn't be starting a business (aka never start a business venture solo). Though from all of this seems like you are in need more help than can be given here. Check out some books on starting business.

Comment: Are you asking about how to get hired for such a role, or how to be qualified to have such responsibilities for a company you start yourself?

Comment: Cross-posted on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64819465/should-i-become-a-senior-programmer-before-i-can-become-a-software-architect-lea

Comment: One of the greatest predictors for future success is past success. Do you have any?

Comment: After reaching a certain level of seniority, it isn't just about technological knowledge. You will never have all the knowledge needed in a software project of a certain size,, so you will always need to rely on someone who has knowledge you don't have. 
You will have to learn how to lead people who know more than you.

Comment: @dan.mwasuser2321368: The second.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it's hard(maybe impossible, as I tried it for few years) to become a senior developer... I like to have developer teams that I can telling them about my ideas and what products I need, then they will creat it perfectly

Sounds like you actually want to be a CEO. There are CEOs who got there by just being good at raising funds. And others who were great at technology first. All of them have a strong vision for what they want to create even if they don't understand all the technical details.

Comment: a product owner or manager would be a start in that direction, given the quote.